# While Loop Problems?

Tags: java, while-loop

Every time I type in a choice from a list of options it just keeps telling me to type in a choice again, it is only supposed to do this when the user types in something that is not an option.

I was having this same problem with the while loop for the yes and no options, but after fixing that I can't see any differences between that and the area where I am still having the problem besides the more options.

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package testing.tests;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author andyoppenheimer
 */
public class TestingTests {

    static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here    

        String start_end;
        String test_run = null;
        int name_num = 0;
        int LOOP_1 = 0;
        int LOOP_2 = 0;

        while (LOOP_1 == 0) {
            System.out.println("Do you want to continue, yes or no?");
            System.out.print("----->: ");
            start_end = sc.next();
            if ("yes".equals(start_end)) {
                LOOP_1 = 1;
            }
            if ("no".equals(start_end)) {
                LOOP_1 = 1;
                System.exit(0);
            }
            if (!"no".equals(start_end) & !"yes".equals(start_end)) {
                LOOP_1 = 0;
            }
        }
```

**

```
while (LOOP_2 == 0) {
            System.out.println("Please pick your test to run.");
            System.out.println("population");
            System.out.println("income");
            System.out.println("password");
            System.out.println("randomize");
            System.out.print("----->: ");
            test_run = sc.next();
            if (!"population".equals(test_run) && !"income".equals(test_run) && !"password".equals(test_run) && !"randomize".equals(test_run)) {
                LOOP_2 = 0;
            }
            if ("population".equals(test_run) & "income".equals(test_run) & "password".equals(test_run) & "randomize".equals(test_run)) {
                LOOP_2 = 1;
            }
```

**

```
        }

        if ("population".equals(test_run)) {
        }

        if ("income".equals(test_run)) {
        }

        if ("password".equals(test_run)) {
        }

        if ("randomize".equals(test_run)) {
            System.out.println("Enter the number of names that will be randomized.");
            System.out.print("----->: ");
            name_num = sc.nextInt();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Now would be a great time to learn how to properly use a `debugger`. Fire up some breakpoints at different points in your `loops` and test to see which variable is causing trouble.

Comment: Yeah, a debugger. Put some breakpoints, and if you are using == to compare Strings, replace it with equals(). (But i haven't found any == with strings at the time this comment was wroten)

Answer (score 4):

Change this line

```
if ("population".equals(test_run) & "income".equals(test_run) & "password".equals(test_run)& "randomize".equals(test_run)) {
        LOOP_2 = 1;
    }
```

to

```
if ("population".equals(test_run) || "income".equals(test_run) || "password".equals(test_run)
            || "randomize".equals(test_run)) {
    LOOP_2 = 1;
}
```

---

**`||`** is the logical OR operator, that's what you should use.

**`&`** evaluates both sides of the operation, so your `if` will evaluate `test_run` to be equal to `"population"`, `"income"`, `"password"` and `"randomize"`, which is impossible.

**Edit:**

Since the first `if` is not changing anything (`LOOP_2` will retain its value `0`), I would ommit that whole `if`, in other words, delete the first `if`

```
// Delete this
if (!"population".equals(test_run) && !"income".equals(test_run) && !"password".equals(test_run) && !"randomize".equals(test_run)) {
    LOOP_2 = 0;
}
```

Comment: Additionally, considering this statement is testing the exact opposite of the preceding if statement, all you need to use is "else".

Comment: @JaTochNietDan yes you are right, but it would be better to delete the first `if` statement since it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

This statement:

```
if ("population".equals(test_run) & "income".equals(test_run) &
"password".equals(test_run) & "randomize".equals(test_run)) {
            LOOP_2 = 1;
        }
```

will never execute. You should be using the or operator `||`, instead of `&`. As the code currently stands, for this condition to evaluate true `test_run` has to be equal to all of the choices, which isn't possible.